# Wordpress Widget Show Pages within Pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm looking for a wordpress widget (Or code snippet) that when displayed on a page will display all sub pages.

Example

```
Page Set 1
 --- Page 1
 --- Page 2
Page Set 2
 --- Page 3
```

So if it was places on Page Set 1 it would only display Page 1 and 2

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your query correctly, you don't need a plugin. Try pasting this into the `sidebar.php` file of your theme just after your opening `<ul>` tag.

```
<?php // subpage support
      $children = wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of='.$post->ID.'&echo=0&depth=1');
      if ($children) { ?>
      <li>
      <h2>More</h2>
      <ul>
      <?php echo $children; ?>
      </ul>
      </li>
<? } ?>
```

If you haven't already, you might like to create a child theme to protect your changes from future upgrades.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to have a list of all the subpages on all pages where you include some meta-code?

If so, the [List Subpages Plugin for Wordpress](http://www.dagondesign.com/articles/list-subpages-plugin-for-wordpress/) might be what you are looking for. It did the trick for me.

Comment: By the way, I see that the plugin is quite old now. It still works on a Wordpress 3.0 installation I've got though.